# netconfig won't change DNS on opensuse 12.2

Tags: domain-name-system, opensuse, networkmanager

I'm trying to update my dns servers after openvpn connection, but netconfig won't do that for me.

Here's how I'm trying to do it [manually now]:

```
/sbin/netconfig modify -v -i tap0 -s openvpn <<-EOF
INTERFACE='tap0'
DNSSERVERS='10.10.0.1'
EOF
```

And here's the verbose output:

```
debug: lockfile created (/var/run/netconfig.pid) for PID 5530
debug: lockfile created
debug: write new STATE file /var/run/netconfig//tap0/netconfig0
debug: Module order: dns-resolver dns-bind dns-dnsmasq nis ntp-runtime
debug: dns-resolver module called
debug: Static Fallback
debug: Use NetworkManager policy merged settings
debug: exec get_dns_settings: /var/run/netconfig/NetworkManager.netconfig
debug:      get_dns_settings: service 'NetworkManager' => rank '1'
debug:      get_dns_settings: DNS_SEARCHLIST_1='mydomain.com'
debug:      get_dns_settings: DNS_SERVERS_1='192.168.0.1'
debug: exit get_dns_settings: /var/run/netconfig/NetworkManager.netconfig
debug: write_resolv_conf: ' mydomain.com ' ' 192.168.0.1 '
debug: No changes for /etc/resolv.conf
debug: dns-bind Module called
debug: dns-dnsmasq Module called
debug: nis Module called
debug: Static Fallback
debug: Use NetworkManager policy merged settings
debug: exec get_nis_settings: /var/run/netconfig/NetworkManager.netconfig
debug: exit get_nis_settings: /var/run/netconfig/NetworkManager.netconfig
debug: set_nisdomainname:  eth0 24
debug: set_nisdomainname: => yes
debug: set_nisdomainname: old[]=, new[24]=
debug: format_yp_conf called with :
debug: Using static fallback
debug: format_static[0] called
debug: No changes for /etc/yp.conf
debug: nis domainname '' is up to date
debug: ntp-runtime Module called
debug: Static Fallback
debug: Use NetworkManager policy merged settings
debug: exec get_ntp_settings: /var/run/netconfig/NetworkManager.netconfig
debug:      get_ntp_settings: NTP_SERVER_LIST=''
debug: exit get_ntp_settings: /var/run/netconfig/NetworkManager.netconfig
```

I've been trying to find something relevant on the web, but failed to do so. I have no other clue on how to progress with this issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

The relevant configuration is in `/etc/sysconfig/network/config`.

When NetworkManager is enabled (`NETWORKMANAGER="yes"`), as it seems to be in your case, the default DNS update policy

```
NETCONFIG_DNS_POLICY="auto"
```

translates to

```
NETCONFIG_DNS_POLICY="STATIC_FALLBACK NetworkManager"
```

as outlined in the netconfig(8) man page. This means the static DNS addresses are included, followed by the ones provided by NetworkManager.

The information you provide manually via `netconfig modify` is considered from `tap0` and so isn't included.

To have your information included, you need to set

```
NETCONFIG_DNS_POLICY="* STATIC_FALLBACK NetworkManager"
```

where the `*` wildcard matches dynamic information from any interface, or you could be more specific

```
NETCONFIG_DNS_POLICY="tap0 STATIC_FALLBACK NetworkManager"
```

note that any policies after NetworkManager are ignored because of the way `/etc/netconfig.d/dns-resolver` is written.